# Exclude a file/directory from SVN in Xcode with SCM

Tags: svn, xcode, version-control

I would like to exclude a directory from my SVN (I'm using Xcode's built in SCM). It's not checked in but I'm just tired of unselecting it from checkin.

Most of my SVN experience is at work on Windows with TortoiseSVN, which has a 'Ignore' function; I assume SCM has that same option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431881/scm-for-xcode) (with answers about Xcode's SVN integration), you could  still go with the "command-line".

See [How to ignore a directory with SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116074/how-to-ignore-a-directory-with-svn)

```
svn propset svn:ignore dirname .
```

You can [see in this Paul Solt's blog entry](http://paulsolt.com/2009/04/using-scm-with-svn-16-and-xcode-312/) an example of a new project, managed by XCode, but with a SVN ignore command

> Make a project in `Xcode` and then use Terminal and execute the commands. If you aren’t familar with `SVN` check out the documentation.

```
cd LOCAL_PROJECT_PATH
svn mkdir SVN_REPOSITORY_LOCATION/PROJECT_NAME
svn co SVN_REPOSITORY_LOCATION/PROJECT_NAME .
svn add *
svn revert --recursive build
svn ps svn:ignore build .
svn ci
```

> The commands:
>
> - create a folder in your SVN repository.
> - Next it checks out the remote repository folder into the local project folder and add all of the project files.
> - Once the files are “added” you’ll want to remove the build directory and ignore it from your SVN repository.
> - Lastly it’ll commit the changes and your project is in the repository.

Answer (score 0):

VocC is on the money, but don't we also want to ignore the pbxuser files and mode1v3 files?

I would change the svn ps svn:ignore build . step for this:

```
svn propset svn:ignore "*.mode1v3
*.pbxuser
bin" .
```