# iPhone, XCode and Source Control

Tags: iphone, xcode, version-control

Up until recently I was working alone on all of my iPhone project code. I recently added another member to my team and was wondering what's the best way to work on the same project together? Where to put the actual code online (right now we're using dropbox)? Which source/version control tools are best to use with small teams working mainly with XCode?

If you have any recommendations, I would love to hear them.
Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431881/scm-for-xcode

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[git](http://git-scm.com/) is very popular these days. There are sites like http://www.github.com that host your projects, or you can setup a repository on your own server. It's easy to use from the command line or external graphical tools.

Getting used to source code management will take your team some time to get used to, so you might want to sit together for a day or to and do some tests with an example project.

Comment: Our team is also using git now. It becomes more and more popular. In the next XCode, XCode 4, git and svn will be integrated into XCode

Comment: Cool any idea when XCode 4 is coming out?

Answer (score 4):

Xcode have built-in support for subversion (svn) "out of the box". If you don't have your own server to host the repository you can sign up with a number of companies that provides these for free or paid depending on your sertup.

One of the companies that provides hosting is [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com/). They offer a [free account](https://signup.beanstalkapp.com/accounts/new?plan=free) (one repository, 3 users and 100 MB) as well as several levels of [paid hosting](http://beanstalkapp.com/pricing). In addition to svn they also offer hosting of git, but then you will not get it fully integrated in Xcode without some extra work.