# How to set up an SCM in Xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode

I know Xcode can be hooked up to an SCM. But how would I set this up from scratch? How to check out / commit files into that, after setting it up?

Comment: Do you already have a working subversion, perforce or cvs server?

Comment: No... not sure how to set this up

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A great guide for setting up subversion repository & configuring with XCode - http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/version-control-is-your-friend.html

Other useful resources -

1) http://developer.apple.com/tools/subversionxcode.html

2) [Which SCM system for Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/431881/scm-for-xcode)

3) http://www.covertapps.com/development/6-setting-up-your-xcode-scm-repositories

Thanks,

Sagar

Answer (score 3):

Once it is set up, several new menu items appear in the SCM menu.  You can right-click over specific filenames and perform some SCM operations that way.

You can also right-click over "Groups & Files" and enable "SCM" there, which will show which files are new or modified.

I never used Xcode's SCM features for anything more than to see what files I've modified, a feature that only helped me find the code I was currently fixing.  For all the updates & commits, I would use the command line, but that's a personal preference.  I'm a long-time command-line CVS and SVN user.  It is faster for me on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

I highly recommend starting with [git](http://git-scm.com/) - while I once preferred perforce I don't like paying for it and lack of Xcode integration makes it tedious. Git is supported in Xcode 4. Using it without integration for a month or two would be invaluable as you will then understand more of what is going on... SCM, like data backups, is only any good when you understand it and use it right.

I like git because it can be used as a local SCM with replication/sync with a central repository. It is widely used and actively maintained. It is free & open source, and I have used it as part of a team delivering a very complex and successful iPhone app.

I really like Git Tower as a GUI.