# How to use version control with Xcode?

Tags: iphone

How to use version control with Xcode?

Comment: Is it something like: http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/03/version-control-is-your-friend.html

Comment: -1: what have you tried? theres a sweet thing called google that has all kinds of answers to this question.

Comment: What version (source) control management system? CVS? Subversion? Perforce? Git? Mercurial?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to set up an SCM in Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852986/how-to-set-up-an-scm-in-xcode)

Comment: @JesseNaugher Ironically this is now the top hit on google for xcode version control

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please read the [Xcode Guide 'Save and Revert Changes to Projects'](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_User_Guide/085-Save_and_Revert_Changes_to_Projects/manage_project_changes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010215-CH7-SW12)

Comment: why was this just upvoted? I don't get it. ^^ That link was broken.

Comment: I guess we just love oneliner-answers to crappy questions :)