# Missing import function SCM in Xcode?

Tags: svn, xcode, version-control

I've followed this link:
[How to set up an SCM in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852986/how-to-set-up-an-scm-in-xcode)
However when opening the window to import the repository I have only the repository bar and no import features.

I have also run the command line 'svnadmin verify [my svn directory]' as well as seeing the green light in the configure repository window

Should I reinstall SCM somehow?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is it possible that somehow the toolbar in the repositories window lost its entries?
Can you provide a screenshot?

Or are you referring to the window where you have to configure your repository? The one with the + and - Buttons below the repo-sidebar?
Then you have to configure your repository first, by pressing the plus button...

Comment: http://img88.imageshack.us/img88/9525/screenshot20101008at728.png Thanks fluchtpunkt! Here's a screenshot... It does appear as if the toolbar no longer is associated with SVN actions. I should say previously I installed Cornerstone so that probably broke something. :-/