# Share Xcode project between multiple developers

Tags: xcode, version-control

I have a project and I want to work with another developer on the same project. I'm looking for a way to share the project between us, so that we can work on it parallel at the same time. I need it to work locally, without using an internet connection.

Comment: best way is git. supported via xcode GUI as also via console. I can only recommand using git and not starting with SVN, the speed and the possibilities are much better there ;)

Comment: Too broad and can't really understand, voting to close.

Comment: This question isn't related to neither iPhone, iOS or Xcode. Use a [DVCS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_version_control_system).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already have **[Git](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13771/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-6)** available to you inside of XCode. You can share your code and work on it on the same time using "branching" mechanisms.

**[Bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/)** has excellent FREE *private* mode where you and **5 other people can share a Git repository**. There are **easy-to-use tutorials** available on their site. I would highly suggest using that.

I would steer away from using SVN, there are better tools for what you are looking for.

Comment: if there any tutorial how to start using

Comment: Signup for Bitbucket... there's a REALLY easy tutorial once you create your first repository. Again, its free and you just need to do the leg work to get started.

Answer (score 7):

I'm a part of a 2-3 iOS developers team so I can give you a few tips from my experience on collaborating (we use git, I'm assuming you know a bit about. if not, [read this](http://git-scm.com/book)), after you get the hang of it here are my thoughts -

- Try to make as little change as you can to your project pbx file simultaneity, It'll result in a conflict almost every time
- Don't be scared of branches, we're using them all the time, if you two are planning to work on different features of the same product try to do it in different branches
- We had serious problems with **storyboards** and collaboration - like pbx their content change even on open and merging those changes can be very tiring

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use SVN ?

You can configure `SVN` in `Xcode` for doing this. Also you can use `Git`.

Check:

1. [Configuring Xcode to use subversion](http://osxdaily.com/2010/06/03/configuring-xcode-to-use-subversion/)
2. [Git Source Control With Xcode](http://www.raywenderlich.com/13771/how-to-use-git-source-control-with-xcode-in-ios-6)

Comment: if there any tutorial how to start using

Comment: @Alkalouti: Did you check the links I attached

Comment: I would REALLY recommend using git instead of SVN - if you don't know anything about both then go ahead and take a look into git. Why learning old technologies when there are new ones?

Answer (score 1):

Check this question [How to set up an SCM in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3852986/how-to-set-up-an-scm-in-xcode).
There you will get links about how to setup SCM for xcode