# Alternative to using Xcode with Subversion

Tags: xcode, svn

Seemed great to have subversion integrated in Xcode.  However it is very primative compared to other IDEs.  Are there another programs out there that I can use to manage Subversion for my iPhone project?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which SCM system for Xcode?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/431881/which-scm-system-for-xcode)

Comment: 1) Completely unrelated to Objective-C: tag removed. 2) Why switching to a new IDE when you can just use a separate app like Versions or Cornerstone? iOS development in an IDE not Xcode or Emacs is a hell, which I know from personal experience.

Comment: The possible duplicate is a different question.  It is not what SCM system.  It is what program can I use for SVN besides XCode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Versions](http://www.versionsapp.com) can do a lot of the things that go beyond what the SVN integration in Xcode can do.

Answer (score 0):

I use [SmartSVN](https://www.smartsvn.com/) and like it a lot. Even the free-of-charge Foundation version is decent IMO. You may also try Professional version for a month to decide whether you need it. [Features](https://www.smartsvn.com/features/) I like most: change sets (Pro only), applying patches (Pro only), their built-in change viewer + editor. The built-in conflict solver could be better, but an external tool can be used instead.